# vkSdkShouldPresentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

новичок на IOS.
`vkSdkShouldPresentViewController` - определен в отдельном классе (не `ViewController`) и, следовательно, не открывает сафари. Сам вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы сафари открывал страницу сафари?

Comment: Что значит "чтобы сафари открывал страницу сафари" ? Требуется уточнение что должно происходить в момент вызова `vkSdkShouldPresentViewController`

Comment: есть два класса. 1 - AuthClass в котором SocialAuth.autWthVk(); 2- класс SocialAuth ->autWthVk(). 2 класс содержит все делегаты вк - vkSdkShouldPresentViewController(); но при вызыве просто выдает error  логах и не открывает сафари или установленный вк приложение.

<code>- (void)vkSdkShouldPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"vkSdkShouldPresentViewController");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    
}</code>